# Explain why a Vat Number Recursive Function isn't Working Correctly

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to make a function that returns True if the number received is a valid VAT number, otherwise False.

And for the number to be valid, the algorithm is:

> let s be the sum of the products of the 8th digit by 2, of the 7th
> number by 3, the 6th number by 4, the 5th number by 5, the 4th by 6,
> the 3rd number by 7, the 2nd number by 8, and the 1st number by 9. Let
> r be the remainder of the integer division of s by 11. otherwise, the
> last digit must be 11 subtracted from r

and so I made this function:

```
verify :: Int -> Bool
verify x
    | r (s (x`div`10) 2 0) == 0 && x `mod` 10 == 0 = True
    | r (s (x`div`10) 2 0) == 1 && x `mod` 10 == 0 = True
    | x `mod` 10 == (s (x`div`10) 2 0) - 11 = True
    | otherwise = False

s :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
s x y acc
    | x `div`10 == x = (acc + x*y)
    | otherwise = ((x `mod` 10)*y + s (x`div`10) (y+1) acc+((x `mod` 10)*y))

r :: Int -> Int
r x = x `mod` 11
```

But when I run `verify 502618418` it should return `True` but the function always return `False` (for any number). And I don't understand why?

Comment: The function `r` always calls itself, at every step, regardless of what the parameters are. Stack overflow is absolutely expected.

Comment: Try getting the number as a list of digits first. Then think about computing the checksum.

Comment: You're recursively going down in `r` without an escape condition. You need to define a condition at which `r` resolves to an `Int` without recursively calling itself (think of it like a bottom).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment by Paul Johnson, the first task at hand is to get the list of decimal digits from the vat number.

Maybe it is not a good idea to intertwin the logic that computes the digits with the logic that computes r and s. The resulting code can be difficult to debug.

Let's try to develop the code interactively, using the `ghci` interpreter.

### Getting the list of decimal digits:

For that, we can first cheat a little bit, just using the `Show` instance for integers.

```
$ ghci
 GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> vat1 = 502618411
 λ> 
 λ> vat1
 502618411
 λ> 
 λ> show vat1
"502618411"
 λ>
```

But in Haskell, `String`'s are just lists of `Char`'s. So this is the same thing as: `['5', '0', '2', '6', '1', '8', '4', '1', '1']`.

```
 λ> 
 λ> show vat1 == ['5', '0', '2', '6', '1', '8', '4', '1', '1']
 True
 λ>
```

We can get numeric [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) codes from the characters using the [`ord`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:ord) function from the `Data.Char` module:

```
 λ> 
 λ> import qualified Data.Char as Ch
 λ> :type Ch.ord
 Ch.ord :: Char -> Int
 λ> 
 λ> map Ch.ord (show vat1)
 [53,48,50,54,49,56,52,49,49]
 λ>
```

As the digits from 0 to 9 appear consecutively in the ASCII sequence (starting at 48), we get the digits by subtracting the code for character '0':

```
 λ> 
 λ> map  (\c -> (Ch.ord c) - (Ch.ord '0'))  (show vat1)
 [5,0,2,6,1,8,4,1,1]
 λ>
```

So we have our list of digits. Let's just define the function:

```
 λ> 
 λ> getDigits vat = map  (\ch -> (Ch.ord ch) - (Ch.ord '0'))  (show vat)
 λ>
 λ> getDigits vat1
 [5,0,2,6,1,8,4,1,1]
 λ>
```

**But what if we don't want to use the Show instance ?**

Then we can use a purely numeric recursive function.
Let's have the list of already produced digits, say `dgs`, as an accumulator. Using the multiline facility in `ghci`:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :{
|λ>  getDigitsR dgs n = let  (q,r) = (divMod n 10)
|λ>                     in   if (q==0) then (r : dgs)
|λ>                                    else getDigitsR (r : dgs) q
|λ> 
|λ>  :}
 λ>
```

Testing:

```
 λ> 
 λ> getDigitsR [9,9,9] vat1
 [5,0,2,6,1,8,4,1,1,9,9,9]
 λ> 
 λ> getDigitsR [] vat1
 [5,0,2,6,1,8,4,1,1]
 λ>
```

So we can write our alternative definition for `getDigits`:

```
 λ> 
 λ> getDigits vat = getDigitsR [] vat
 λ>
```

### Computing r and s:

From the specification, the weight of a digit starts at 9 and get decreased by 1 at every step. Below a weight of 2, the summation stops. This leads to the following recursive definition for computing `s` from the digits of the vat number:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :{
|λ> getSr w [] = 0
|λ> getSr w (dg:dgs) = if (w < 2) then  0  else  (w*dg + getSr (w-1) dgs)
|λ> :}
 λ>
 λ> 
 λ> digits1
 [5,0,2,6,1,8,4,1,1]
 λ> 
 λ> getSr 9 digits1
 146
 λ>
```

This leads to this simple function for computing s:

```
 λ> 
 λ> getS vat = getSr 9 (getDigits vat)
 λ>
```

**But what if a library-using style is preferred ?**

It is commonly held that Haskell programmers, as they get more experience, tend to use less direct manual recursion and more *internally recursive* library functions.

If we want to do that here, we need to *zip* the weights with the digits:

```
 λ> 
 λ> ws = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2]
 λ> digits = getDigits vat1
 λ> 
 λ> zip ws digits
 [(9,5),(8,0),(7,2),(6,6),(5,1),(4,8),(3,4),(2,1)]
 λ>
```

at which point we can do the multiplications and sum their results:

```
 λ> 
 λ> map (\(w,d) -> w*d) (zip ws digits)
 [45,0,14,36,5,32,12,2]
 λ> 
 λ> sum $ map (\(w,d) -> w*d) (zip ws digits)
 146
 λ>
```

Library function [zipWith](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) makes a simplification possible:

```
 λ> 
 λ> sum $ zipWith (*) ws digits
 146
 λ>
```

So we can write an alternative version of our `getS` function:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :{
|λ> getS vat = let  ws     = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2] 
|λ>                 digits = getDigits vat
|λ>            in   sum $ zipWith (*) ws digits
|λ> :}
 λ> 
 λ> getS vat1
 146
 λ>
```

Note that this style makes it easier to deal with arbitrary weights.

### Conclusion:

Our job is thus essentially complete:

```
 λ> 
 λ> vat1
 502618411
 λ> getS vat1
 146
 λ> r = mod 146 11
 λ> r
 3
 λ>
```

Putting the code into final shape, by picking the styles and providing the type signatures, is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Did know `divMod` was in Prelude.